# Android Firebase-auth crash on RecaptchaActivity

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I have a problem when using Firebase-auth to get OTP SMS. I get the following crash:

```
.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {id.app.android/com.google.firebase.auth.internal.RecaptchaActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzat com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzdk.zza()' on a null object reference
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4270)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4302)
   at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2044)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)

Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzat com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzdk.zza()' on a null object reference
   at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzk.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.1:2)
   at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.RecaptchaActivity.zzd(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.1:10)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzth.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.1:13)
   at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.RecaptchaActivity.onResume(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.1:43)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1454)
   at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:8050)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4260)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4302)
   at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2044)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

I've added "implementation 'androidx.browser: browser: 1.3.0'" in gradle and api's & service settings in google cloud but it still doesn't work

Anyone can help me?
thanks..

Comment: I started getting the same crash altho this worked perfectly before. Found any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I was reviewing the problem, I had it too, what I did was disable the backup copies of the phone on which I was testing. I uninstalled the application and reinstalled it from android studio and it worked. Given this, I think it is time to investigate the backups and how this affects the app

[image]

[image]

If someone could help us with this relationship I would be very grateful.

You can also change this in the android manifest and reinstall, I may not be right so I'm open to suggestions, but this worked for me.

(Text written by google translator)

[image]